# How can add interaction and animation to shapes drawn in Processing?

Tags: processing

I'm trying to code a canvas full of shapes(houses) and animate them in processing.

Here's an example of shape:

```java
void house(int x, int y) { 
  pushMatrix(); 
  translate(x, y); 
  fill(0, 200, 0); 
  triangle(15, 0, 0, 15, 30, 15); 
  rect(0, 15, 30, 30); 
  rect(12, 30, 10, 15); 
  popMatrix();
}
```

By animation I mean moving them in random directions.

I would also like to add basic interaction: when hovering over a house it's colour would change.

At the moment I've managed to render a canvas full of houses:

```java
void setup() { 
  size(500, 500); 
  background(#74F5E9); 
  for (int i = 30; i < 500; i = i + 100) { 
    for (int j = 30; j < 500; j = j + 100) { 
      house(i, j);
    }
  }
} 
void house(int x, int y) { 
  pushMatrix(); 
  translate(x, y); 
  fill(0, 200, 0); 
  triangle(15, 0, 0, 15, 30, 15); 
  rect(0, 15, 30, 30); 
  rect(12, 30, 10, 15); 
  popMatrix();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry about this, but questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. I encourage you to post again, but beforehand you should read the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, which will give you pointers about what and how to ask a question to maximize your chances of getting a good answer. Don't let this first experience discourage you, this community is amazing, but you have to play by it's rules!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing source code: your attempted sketch it's very hard to tell.

They can be animated in many ways and it's unclear what you mean. For example, is that the position/rotation/scale of each square, is it the corners/vertices of each square, both ?

You might have a clear idea in your mind, but the current form of the question is ambiguous. We also don't know you're comfort level with various notions such as classes/objects/PVector/PShape/etc. If you were to 'story board' this animation what would it look like ? Breaking the problem down and explaining it in a way that anyone can understand might actually help you figure out a solution on your own as well.

Processing has plenty of examples. Here are a few I find relevant based on what my understanding is of your problem.

You can have a look at the Objects and Create Shapes examples:

1. **File > Examples > Basics > Objects > Objects**: Demonstrates grouping drawing/animation (easing, damping). You can tweak this example draw a single square and once you're happy with the look/motion you can animate multiple using an array or [ArrayList](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html)
2. **File > Examples > Topics > Create Shapes > PolygonPShapeOOP3**: Great example using [PShape](https://processing.org/reference/PShape.html) to animate objects.
3. **File > Examples > Topics > Create Shapes > WigglePShape**: This example demonstrates how to access and modify the vertices of a `PShape`

For reference I'm simply copy/pasting the examples mentioned above here as well:

**Objects**

```java
/**
 * Objects
 * by hbarragan. 
 * 
 * Move the cursor across the image to change the speed and positions
 * of the geometry. The class MRect defines a group of lines.
 */

MRect r1, r2, r3, r4;
 
void setup()
{
  size(640, 360);
  fill(255, 204);
  noStroke();
  r1 = new MRect(1, 134.0, 0.532, 0.1*height, 10.0, 60.0);
  r2 = new MRect(2, 44.0, 0.166, 0.3*height, 5.0, 50.0);
  r3 = new MRect(2, 58.0, 0.332, 0.4*height, 10.0, 35.0);
  r4 = new MRect(1, 120.0, 0.0498, 0.9*height, 15.0, 60.0);
}
 
void draw()
{
  background(0);
  
  r1.display();
  r2.display();
  r3.display();
  r4.display();
 
  r1.move(mouseX-(width/2), mouseY+(height*0.1), 30);
  r2.move((mouseX+(width*0.05))%width, mouseY+(height*0.025), 20);
  r3.move(mouseX/4, mouseY-(height*0.025), 40);
  r4.move(mouseX-(width/2), (height-mouseY), 50);
}
 
class MRect 
{
  int w; // single bar width
  float xpos; // rect xposition
  float h; // rect height
  float ypos ; // rect yposition
  float d; // single bar distance
  float t; // number of bars
 
  MRect(int iw, float ixp, float ih, float iyp, float id, float it) {
    w = iw;
    xpos = ixp;
    h = ih;
    ypos = iyp;
    d = id;
    t = it;
  }
 
  void move (float posX, float posY, float damping) {
    float dif = ypos - posY;
    if (abs(dif) > 1) {
      ypos -= dif/damping;
    }
    dif = xpos - posX;
    if (abs(dif) > 1) {
      xpos -= dif/damping;
    }
  }
 
  void display() {
    for (int i=0; i<t; i++) {
      rect(xpos+(i*(d+w)), ypos, w, height*h);
    }
  }
}
```

**PolygonPShapeOOP3**:

```java
/**
 * PolygonPShapeOOP. 
 * 
 * Wrapping a PShape inside a custom class 
 * and demonstrating how we can have a multiple objects each
 * using the same PShape.
 */


// A list of objects
ArrayList<Polygon> polygons;

// Three possible shapes
PShape[] shapes = new PShape[3];

void setup() {
  size(640, 360, P2D);
  
  shapes[0] = createShape(ELLIPSE,0,0,100,100);
  shapes[0].setFill(color(255, 127));
  shapes[0].setStroke(false);
  shapes[1] = createShape(RECT,0,0,100,100);
  shapes[1].setFill(color(255, 127));
  shapes[1].setStroke(false);
  shapes[2] = createShape();  
  shapes[2].beginShape();
  shapes[2].fill(0, 127);
  shapes[2].noStroke();
  shapes[2].vertex(0, -50);
  shapes[2].vertex(14, -20);
  shapes[2].vertex(47, -15);
  shapes[2].vertex(23, 7);
  shapes[2].vertex(29, 40);
  shapes[2].vertex(0, 25);
  shapes[2].vertex(-29, 40);
  shapes[2].vertex(-23, 7);
  shapes[2].vertex(-47, -15);
  shapes[2].vertex(-14, -20);
  shapes[2].endShape(CLOSE);

  // Make an ArrayList
  polygons = new ArrayList<Polygon>();
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    int selection = int(random(shapes.length));        // Pick a random index
    Polygon p = new Polygon(shapes[selection]);        // Use corresponding PShape to create Polygon
    polygons.add(p);
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(102);

  // Display and move them all
  for (Polygon poly : polygons) {
    poly.display();
    poly.move();
  }
}

// A class to describe a Polygon (with a PShape)

class Polygon {
  // The PShape object
  PShape s;
  // The location where we will draw the shape
  float x, y;
  // Variable for simple motion
  float speed;

  Polygon(PShape s_) {
    x = random(width);
    y = random(-500, -100); 
    s = s_;
    speed = random(2, 6);
  }
  
  // Simple motion
  void move() {
    y+=speed;
    if (y > height+100) {
      y = -100;
    }
  }
  
  // Draw the object
  void display() {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(x, y);
    shape(s);
    popMatrix();
  }
}
```

**WigglePShape:**

```java
/**
 * WigglePShape. 
 * 
 * How to move the individual vertices of a PShape
 */


// A "Wiggler" object
Wiggler w;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360, P2D);
  w = new Wiggler();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  w.display();
  w.wiggle();
}

// An object that wraps the PShape

class Wiggler {
  
  // The PShape to be "wiggled"
  PShape s;
  // Its location
  float x, y;
  
  // For 2D Perlin noise
  float yoff = 0;
  
  // We are using an ArrayList to keep a duplicate copy
  // of vertices original locations.
  ArrayList<PVector> original;

  Wiggler() {
    x = width/2;
    y = height/2; 

    // The "original" locations of the vertices make up a circle
    original = new ArrayList<PVector>();
    for (float a = 0; a < radians(370); a += 0.2) {
      PVector v = PVector.fromAngle(a);
      v.mult(100);
      original.add(new PVector());
      original.add(v);
    }
    
    // Now make the PShape with those vertices
    s = createShape();
    s.beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    s.fill(80, 139, 255);
    s.noStroke();
    for (PVector v : original) {
      s.vertex(v.x, v.y);
    }
    s.endShape(CLOSE);
  }

  void wiggle() {
    float xoff = 0;
    // Apply an offset to each vertex
    for (int i = 1; i < s.getVertexCount(); i++) {
      // Calculate a new vertex location based on noise around "original" location
      PVector pos = original.get(i);
      float a = TWO_PI*noise(xoff,yoff);
      PVector r = PVector.fromAngle(a);
      r.mult(4);
      r.add(pos);
      // Set the location of each vertex to the new one
      s.setVertex(i, r.x, r.y);
      // increment perlin noise x value
      xoff+= 0.5;
    }
    // Increment perlin noise y value
    yoff += 0.02;
  }

  void display() {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(x, y);
    shape(s);
    popMatrix();
  }
}
```

**Update**

Based on your comments here's an version of your sketch modified so the color of the hovered house changes:

```
// store house bounding box dimensions for mouse hover check
int houseWidth  = 30;
// 30 px rect height + 15 px triangle height
int houseHeight = 45;

void setup() { 
  size(500, 500); 
}

void draw(){
  background(#74F5E9); 
  for (int i = 30; i < 500; i = i + 100) { 
    for (int j = 30; j < 500; j = j + 100) {
      // check if the cursor is (roughly) over a house
      // and render with a different color
      if(overHouse(i, j)){
        house(i, j, color(0, 0, 200));
      }else{
        house(i, j, color(0, 200, 0));
      }
    }
  }
}

void house(int x, int y, color fillColor) { 
  pushMatrix(); 
  translate(x, y); 
  fill(fillColor); 
  triangle(15, 0, 0, 15, 30, 15); 
  rect(0, 15, 30, 30); 
  rect(12, 30, 10, 15); 
  popMatrix();
}

// from Processing RollOver example
// https://processing.org/examples/rollover.html
boolean overRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
  if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x+width && 
      mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y+height) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

// check if the mouse is within the bounding box of a house
boolean overHouse(int x, int y){
  // offset half the house width since the pivot is at the tip of the house 
  // the horizontal center
  return overRect(x - (houseWidth / 2), y, houseWidth, houseHeight);
}
```

The code is commented, but here are the main takeaways:

- the `house()` function has been changed so you can specify a color
- the `overRect()` function has been copied from the Rollover example
- the `overHouse()` function uses `overRect()`, but adds a horizontal offset to take into account the house is drawn from the middle top point (the house tip is the shape's pivot point)

Regarding animation, Processing has tons of [examples](https://processing.org/examples/):

- https://processing.org/examples/sinewave.html
- https://processing.org/examples/additivewave.html
- https://processing.org/examples/noise1d.html
- https://processing.org/examples/noisewave.html
- https://processing.org/examples/arrayobjects.html
- and well as the Motion / Simulate / Vectors sections:

[image: Processing examples: Motion / Simulate / Vectors screenshot of the bottom of the page which includes thumbnails]

Let's start take sine motion as an example.
The [`sin()`](https://processing.org/reference/sin_.html) function takes an angle (in radians by default) and returns a value between -1.0 and 1.0

Since you're already calculating positions for each house within a 2D grid, you can offset each position using `sin()` to animate it. The nice thing about it is cyclical: no matter what angle you provide you always get values between -1.0 and 1.0. This would save you the trouble of needing to store the current x, y positions of each house in arrays so you can increment them in a different directions.

Here's a modified version of the above sketch that uses `sin()` to animate:

```java
// store house bounding box dimensions for mouse hover check
int houseWidth  = 30;
// 30 px rect height + 15 px triangle height
int houseHeight = 45;

void setup() { 
  size(500, 500); 
}

void draw(){
  background(#74F5E9); 
  for (int i = 30; i < 500; i = i + 100) { 
    for (int j = 30; j < 500; j = j + 100) {
      
      // how fast should each module move around a circle (angle increment)
      // try changing i with j, adding i + j or trying other mathematical expressions
      // also try changing 0.05 to other values
      float phase = (i + frameCount) * 0.05;
      // try changing amplitude to other values
      float amplitude = 30.0;
      // map the sin() result from it's range to a pixel range (-30px to 30px for example)
      float xOffset = map(sin(phase), -1.0, 1.0, -amplitude, amplitude);
      // offset each original grid horizontal position (i) by the mapped sin() result
      float x = i + xOffset;
      // check if the cursor is (roughly) over a house
      // and render with a different color
      if(overHouse(i, j)){
        house(x, j, color(0, 0, 200));
      }else{
        house(x, j, color(0, 200, 0));
      }
    }
  }
}

void house(float x, float y, color fillColor) { 
  pushMatrix(); 
  translate(x, y); 
  fill(fillColor); 
  triangle(15, 0, 0, 15, 30, 15); 
  rect(0, 15, 30, 30); 
  rect(12, 30, 10, 15); 
  popMatrix();
}

// from Processing RollOver example
// https://processing.org/examples/rollover.html
boolean overRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
  if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x+width && 
      mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y+height) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

// check if the mouse is within the bounding box of a house
boolean overHouse(int x, int y){
  // offset half the house width since the pivot is at the tip of the house 
  // the horizontal center
  return overRect(x - (houseWidth / 2), y, houseWidth, houseHeight);
}
```

Read through the comments and try to tweak the code to get a better understanding of how it works and have fun coming up with different animations.

The main changes are:

- modifying the `house()` function to use float x,y positions (instead of int): this is to avoid converting `float` to `int` when using `sin()`, `map()` and get smoother motions (instead of motion that "snaps" to whole pixels)
- Mapped sine to positions which can be used to animate

Wrapping the 3 instructions that calculate the x offset into a reusable function would allow you do further experiment. What if you used a similar technique the y position of each house ? What about both x and y ?

Go through the code step by step. Try to understand it, change it, break it, fix it and make new sketches reusing code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. The polygon part is close to my answer but as I am a beginner in processing I would request simple codes. What I am actually searching for is…(Step 1) Draw any shape in Canvas( let’s take 4 rectangle) at equal distance from each other.(Step 2) Code to move the four rectangles in any direction (just any animation, simpler would be appreciative). (Step 3) Insert some effect in the rectangle while we move the mouse. I would be really glad if you can write the codes for Step 1,2 and 3 in different steps ( not continuously in a single page). Please Help.

Comment: You should edit your question to include these comments: it's a great improvement. When you edit, try to pick a very specific example of what you're aming for, taking into account you can always tweak later (and ask more questions of course). Try to remove any ambiguity. For example (Step 1) 'draw any shape' in implies one shape, but equal distance from each other implies multiple shapes. Replace that with 6 shapes for example. If you can draw 6 you can draw 60 just as easily using a [`for` loop](https://processing.org/reference/for_.html). (Step 2) move the shapes in a random direction...

Comment: ..."(Step 3) Insert some effect in the rectangle while we move the mouse": again, pick a specific example.
Let's say change the fill colour of the shape while hovering over each shape.  Have a look at the [Rollover](https://processing.org/examples/rollover.html) Processing example (the `overRect` function in particular and how it's used). Notice how your one question has multiple questions. I recommend reading Kevin Workman's [How to Program](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) article and following it. Hopefully, step by step you'll iterate to a clear goal and how to get there.

Comment: Ok Sir. I will be asking three questions. (Question1) Code to draw four rectangles in canvas.(Question 2) Code to move the rectangles in  random direction.(Question 3) Code to change the colour of the rectangles while moving the mouse over the canvas.

Comment: So it's easier for everyone that would like to contribute answers, can you please edit your question above to include these details (drawing four rectangles, moving the rectangles in a random direction, changing colour while hovering). You should also post a code snippet which is your attempt to tackle these goals. If this is for an assignment, do mention that and also what you might or might not be able to use. (for example this can be done with classes, ArrayList, PVector, but if this is for a course and you've haven't been introduced to this yet you might need to use `float[]`, etc.)

Comment: <void setup()
{
  size(500, 500);
  background(#74F5E9);
  for (int i = 30; i < 500; i = i + 100){
    for (int j = 30; j < 500; j = j + 100){
    house(i, j);
  }
}
}

void house(int x, int y)
{
  pushMatrix();
  translate(x, y);
  fill(0,200,0);
  triangle(15, 0, 0, 15, 30, 15);
  rect(0, 15, 30, 30);
  rect(12, 30, 10, 15);
  popMatrix();
}/> Ok i am on the half way. I have drawn a shape(house). Can you help me write the code to animate these house may be any animation like changing shape or color. And in second step changing color while hovering. Please Help.

Comment: I meant editing the question. I've edited the question for you. Is this for a coursework ? Have you been introduced to arrays ? What about objects or PVector ?

Comment: @oden I've updated my answer with a couple of basic examples of interaction and animation (avoiding objects/PVector/etc.).

Comment: Thank you so much. It is my assignment and I am beginner in programming so don't have any knowledge on arrays. Anyway thanks for this time.